# Cleaner / reusable way to emit specific JSON for django models

Tags: python, django, json

I'm rewriting the back end of an app to use Django, and I'd like to keep the front end as untouched as possible.  I need to be consistent with the JSON that is sent between projects.

In `models.py` I have:

```
class Resource(models.Model):
    # Name chosen for consistency with old app
    _id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)

    @property
    def bookingPercentage(self):
        from bookings.models import Booking
        return Booking.objects.filter(resource=self)
            .aggregate(models.Sum("percent"))["percent__sum"]
```

And in `views.py` that gets all resource data as JSON:

```
def get_resources(request):
    resources = []
    for resource in Resource.objects.all():
        resources.append({
            "_id": resource._id,
            "name": resource.first,
            "bookingPercentage": resource.bookingPercentage                     
        })
    return HttpResponse(json.dumps(resources))
```

This works exactly as I need it to, but it seems somewhat antithetical to Django and/or Python.  Using `.all().values` will not work because `bookinPercentage` is a derived property.

Another issue is that there are other similar models that will need JSON representations in pretty much the same way.  I would be rewriting similar code and just using different names for the values of the models.  In general is there a better way to do this that is more pythonic/djangothonic/does not require manual creation of the JSON?

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I do in this situation:

```
def get_resources(request):
    resources = list(Resource.objects.all())
    for resource in resources:
        resource.booking = resource.bookingPercentage()
```

That is, I create a new attribute for each entity using the derived property.  It's only a local attribute (not stored in the database), but it's available for your `json.dumps()` call.

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you just want a serialisation of your models, in JSON. You can use the serialisers in core:

```
from django.core import serializers

data = serializers.serialize('json', Resource.objects.all(), fields=('name','_id', 'bookingPercentage'))
```

So just pass in your Model class, and the fields you want to serialize into your view:

```
get_resources(request, model_cls, fields):
```

documentation here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/serialization/#id2

Comment: Including `_id` and `bookingPercentage` in the `fields` does not include them in the JSON, and they are still wrapped inside of an object property `fields`, but I need them to be at the top level.

Comment: Why the downvote, just because my suggestion wasn't to your liking?

Comment: Not that it's not to my liking, but it actually does not work for the reasons I described.  It seems like `fields` can only be used to *limit* fields entries